# After running query in my spring boot project not getting any result

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to fetch data from three tables using the query. I am using the below code in my project.I am not getting any exception while running the code but getting this only=> {} in postman.

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectListingSummaryRepository extends JpaRepository<ProjectListingSummary, Long> {

@Override
@Query(value="SELECT spd.id, spd.pro_name, spd.pro_price, spd.pro_image, spd.pro_name, spd.pro_location, c.ivr_number, c.whatsapp_number, spd.property_type, spd.start_size, spd.end_size, GROUP_CONCAT(spb.bedroom_num)as bedroom_configs FROM `seo_project_details` as spd , city as c, `seo_project_bedrooms` as spb WHERE spd.city = c.id and spd.id = spb.project_id and spd.id = 788 group by spd.id",nativeQuery=true)
List<ProjectListingSummary> findAll();
}
```

Comment: Then your query doesn't return a result. Does this query work if you run it in the SQL query console?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, Yes it works in the sql query console. It returns one row.

Comment: what is ProjectListingSummary?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a `SqlResultSetMapping`. Annotate the class `ProjectListingSummary` with something like this:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "ProjectListingSummaryMapping", columns = {
      @ColumnResult(name="someId", type=Integer.class), // whatever spd.id should map to
      @ColumnResult(name="proName", type=String.class), // whatever spd.pro_name should map to
      @ColumnResult(name="proPrice", type=String.class)  // whatever spd.pro_price should map to
...
})
```

The order of those fields will need to correspond to the order they are in the query.
Since you didn't provide us with the structure of `ProjectListingSummary` I made up those field names.

You will also need to define a `@NamedNativeQuery`, preferably also on the `ProjectListingSummary` class.

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name="ProjectListingSummary.allProjectListingSummaries", 
  resultClass=ProjectListingSummary.class,
  resultSetMapping="ProjectListingSummaryMapping"
  value="SELECT spd.id, spd.pro_name, spd.pro_price, spd.pro_image, spd.pro_name, spd.pro_location, c.ivr_number, c.whatsapp_number, spd.property_type, spd.start_size, spd.end_size, GROUP_CONCAT(spb.bedroom_num)as bedroom_configs FROM `seo_project_details` as spd , city as c, `seo_project_bedrooms` as spb WHERE spd.city = c.id and spd.id = spb.project_id and spd.id = 788 group by spd.id",
  nativeQuery=true)
```

Then you just need to define a method in your repository with the same name as the named query.

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectListingSummaryRepository extends JpaRepository<ProjectListingSummary, Long> {

  List<ProjectListingSummary> allProjectListingSummaries();
}
```